# CircularProgressIndicator not showing during loading Image.network

Tags: flutter

currently I successed to load and display a list of image that I stock in firebase storage, like that

```
getimage()async{


  _imageProviders_pro = [

    Image.network(
      '${ await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL('gs://XXXX-XXXXX.XXX.com/XXX.jpg').getDownloadURL()}',
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
          ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) {
          return child;
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                : null,
          ),
        );
      },
    ).image,

 ...

]
```

Problem, I search to display a CircularProgressIndicator when image is loading, but it doesn't work, I have a blank page, without CircularProgressIndicator.

Here is where my imageprovider_pro is send

```
PageView(
    children: <Widget>[
   
      PageView.builder(
        physics: _pagingEnabled ? const PageScrollPhysics() : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: widget.imageProviders.length,
        controller: _pageController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          final image = widget.imageProviders[index];
          return EasyImageView(
            imageProvider: image,
            onScaleChanged: (scale) {

              setState(() {
                _pagingEnabled = scale <= 1.0;

              });
            },
          );
        },

      
      )
```

---

```
/// A full-sized view that displays the given image, supporting pinch & zoom
class EasyImageView extends StatefulWidget {

  /// The image to display
  final ImageProvider imageProvider;
  /// Minimum scale factor
  final double minScale;
  /// Maximum scale factor
  final double maxScale;
  /// Callback for when the scale has changed, only invoked at the end of
  /// an interaction.
  final void Function(double)? onScaleChanged;
  /// Create a new instance
  const EasyImageView({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageProvider,
    this.minScale = 1.0,
    this.maxScale = 5.0,
    this.onScaleChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EasyImageViewState createState() => _EasyImageViewState();
}

class _EasyImageViewState extends State<EasyImageView> {

  final TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          transformationController: _transformationController,
          minScale: widget.minScale,
          maxScale: widget.maxScale,
          child: Image(image: widget.imageProvider),
          onInteractionEnd: (scaleEndDetails) {
            double scale = _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();

            if (widget.onScaleChanged != null) {
              widget.onScaleChanged!(scale);
            }
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you use stateless widget?

Comment: I use a statefull widget

Comment: not here EasyImageView, I think you used it where you use scaffold widget to init the page

Answer (score 0):

this is works for me .. your bug it's how you call your images to display

```
  Image.network(
              "https://www.sncf-connect.com/assets/styles/ratio_2_1_max_width_961/public/media/2020-11/seinedanslesyvelines-istock-marcelloland.jpg?h=8d8fd87c&itok=Ew0qF8_i",
              loadingBuilder: ((context, child, loadingProgress) {
                if (loadingProgress == null) {
                  return Center(child: child);
                }
                return Center(
                    child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                  animating: true,
                  radius: 20,
                ));
              }),
            ),
```

Comment: This example not working with my code :( yes I have found other problem with my code, I can't display more than 6 images, after It can't load any image... I will create a new question to first restructure this code

Comment: how do you call your function "getImage" ? @Nitneuq

Comment: getimage() is call at the iniState()

Comment: add your code full code @Nitneuq it's here your problem of loading

Comment: I found the solution, I add loadingBuilder : () ... in  child: Image(image: widget.imageProvider) of class EasyImageView

Comment: the problem of limit was due to conflict with other package who search to connect to internet at the same time. All is good